# Can I run Abandoned 2 game on iPad?

Tags: ipad, games

Is it possible to get abandoned 2 on iPad free and unblocked or would it fail? Because I played and beat the 1st in less than a hour and really want to play it on my iPad but cool math games says it’ll only work on a pc/computer.

Answer (score 1):

Games (and applications in general) need to be adapted and compiled specifically for each operating system (like iOS) and hardware (like iPad). So if a game/application is only available for PCs you won't be able to run it on iOS.

The situation is slightly different if you are for instance using a Mac. To run Windows software you can then use Virtualbox and similar software to run Windows on top of macOS.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks but why demote I had a q and asked not trying to be a smart alek

Comment: @OwenLawrence Somebody didn't like the question, or had a bad day, or thought you could have figured it out yourself, or something else. Unless they leave a comment we can't know (and shouldn't loose too much sleep over it).